# Identify pattern in R, counting and assigning values accordingly

Tags: r, loops, pattern-matching

I'm new to R so this question might be quite basic. 
There is a column in my data which goes like 4 4 4 4 7 7 7 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 4 4 7 7 7 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 4 4.....

One cycle of 4...7...13... is considered as one complete run, to which I will assign a Run Number (1, 2, 3...) to each run.

The number of times that each value (4, 7, 13) repeats is not fixed, and the total number of rows in a run is not fixed either. The total number of runs is unknown (but typically ranging from 60-90). The order of (4, 7, 13) is fixed.

I have attached my current code here. It works fine, but it does take a minute or two when there's about a few million rows of data. I'm aware that growing vectors in a for loop is really not recommended in R, so I would like to ask if anyone has a more elegant solution to this.

Sample data can be generated with the code below, and the desired output can also be generated with the sample code below.

```
#Generates sample data
df <- data.frame(Temp = c(sample(50:250, 30)), Pres = c(sample(500:1000, 30)), 
             Message = c(rep(4, 3), rep(7, 2), rep(13, 6), rep(4, 4), rep(7, 1), rep(13, 7), rep(4, 3), rep(7, 4)))
```

**Current Solution**

```
prev_val = 0
Rcount = 1
Run_Count = c()
for (val in df$Message)
{
  delta = prev_val - val
  if((delta == 9))
  Rcount = Rcount + 1
  prev_val = val
  Run_Count = append(Run_Count, Rcount)
}
df$Run = Run_Count
```

The desired output:

```
226 704 4  1
138 709 4  1
136 684 4  1 
 57 817 7  1
187 927 7  1
190 780 13 1
152 825 13 1
126 766 13 1
202 855 13 1
214 757 13 1
172 922 13 1
 50 975 4  2
159 712 4  2
212 802 4  2
181 777 4  2
102 933 7  2
165 753 13 2
 67 962 13 2
119 631 13 2
```

The data frame will later be split by the Run Number, but after being categorized according to the value, i.e.

```
... 4 1 
... 4 1 
... 4 1 
... 4 1 
... 4 2 
... 4 2 
... 4 2 
... 4 3
.....
```

Comment: you might be new to R but you delivered a well-posed question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is an improvement, but it uses the `rle` run length encoding function to determine the length of each repeat in each run.

```
df <- data.frame(Temp = c(sample(50:250, 30)), Pres = c(sample(500:1000, 30)), 
                 Message = c(rep(4, 3), rep(7, 2), rep(13, 6), rep(4, 4), rep(7, 1), rep(13, 7), rep(4, 3), rep(7, 4)))

rleout<-rle(df$Message)
#find the length of the runs and create the numbering
runcounts<-ceiling(length(rleout$lengths)/3)
runs<-rep(1:runcounts, each=3)    

#need to trim the length of run numbers for cases where there is not a  
#   full sequence, as in the test case.
rleout$values<-runs[1:length(rleout$lengths)]

#create the new column
df$out<-inverse.rle(rleout)
```

I'm sure someone can come along and demonstrate and a better and faster method using data tables.

Comment: `rle` is pretty darn quick and should be very competitive speedwise.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, there is just one minor mistake which caused it not to work on my actual data at first. The third line should be **runs <- rep(1:runcounts, each=3)** instead, where 3 is the number of elements in one pattern (4, 7, 13). In the sample data, rucounts happened to be 3 as well, so the code worked for the sample data. Anyways, thank you so much! It is pretty much instantaneous now :)

Comment: @Kaylee, Thanks for the catch.  Made the correction and provided an alternative as another option.

Answer (score 2):

easily use:

```
df$runID <- cumsum(c(-1,diff(df$Message)) < 0)

#    Temp Pres Message runID
# 1   174  910       4     1
# 2   181  612       4     1
# 3   208  645       4     1
# 4    89  601       7     1
# 5   172  812       7     1
# 6   213  672      13     1
# 7   137  848      13     1
# 8   153  833      13     1
# 9   127  591      13     1
# 10  243  907      13     1
# 11  146  599      13     1
# 12  151  567       4     2
# 13  139  855       4     2
# 14  147  793       4     2
# 15  227  533       4     2
# 16  241  959       7     2
# 17  206  948      13     2
# 18  236  875      13     2
# 19  133  537      13     2
# 20   70  688      13     2
# 21  218  528      13     2
# 22  244  927      13     2
# 23  161  697      13     2
# 24  177  572       4     3
# 25  179  911       4     3
# 26  192  559       4     3
# 27   60  771       7     3
# 28  245  682       7     3
# 29  196  614       7     3
# 30  171  536       7     3
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked really well. It also solved a problem that I encountered with the solution using `rle`, which was that when the sequence does not start from 4, like it might go `7 7 13 13 13 4 4 4 7...`. The `rle` approach will take (7, 13, 4) as the pattern instead, but your solution still identifies correctly (I can just discard the first incomplete cycle). I assume it is because it is set to detect the change when the next number is smaller than the previous one?

Comment: yes, it finds the spots when you change from a bigger number (eg. 13) to a smaller (eg. 4). When you go from big to small, that must mean a new cycle has started. You can run the code little by little to see whats going on in detail.